# C - Inserting new node alphabetically into linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I have been reading around and I am still having trouble understanding linked lists. My issue is that for some reason when I traverse the list to determine if any structures in the list have the same name or age it deletes the list or when I try to add a new node into the list it is deleted as well.

The list is dynamic so it I'm not going based off any type of count but how many structures the user decides to enter.

Any direction would be appreciated.

```
int add(char* name, char* genderValueString, char* breed, int age, float weight)
{

int result;
int count = 0;
gender curGen = 1;


struct dog *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct dog));

strcpy(temp->name, name);
strcpy(temp->breed, breed);
temp->age = age;
temp->weight = weight;

if (strcmpi(genderValueString, "male") == 0) {
    curGen = 0;
}
temp->genderValue = curGen;


if (list == NULL) {
    temp->next = list;
    list = temp;
    result = 1;
}

else {

    while (list != NULL) {
        if (strcmpi(list->name, name) == 0 && list->age == age) {
            result = 0;
        }

        else {
            result = 1;
        }

        list = list->next;
    }


    if (result == 1) {
        while (list != NULL) {

            if (strcmpi(list->name, name) > 0 || list->age > age) {

                struct dog *prev = list;
                list = temp;
                list->next = prev;              

            }   

            list = list->next;
        }


    }

}


return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that your variable `list` is a global variable that represents the head of your list.

The main problem in your code is that you're modifying `list` in your while loop (`list = list->next`), which means that you're losing track of the head.

What you could do right now to make your code work (maybe) is to declare another variable that is a copy of the head and that you can safely modify.

For example:

```
struct dog *list_tmp;

...

for (list_tmp = list; list_tmp != NULL; list_tmp = list_tmp->next)
{
    if (strcmpi(list->name, name) == 0 && list->age == age) {
        result = 0;
    }
    ...
}
```

And do that for your two loops.

But bottom line, never modify `list` since it seems to be the only copy of the head of your list ;)

Comment: Thank you so much, but I'm still having a bit of trouble. If I wanted to add something to the list would I add it to the list_tmp and then make the old list equal to the temp list or should I just add it to the original list directly?

Answer (score 0):

I tested this with Visual Studio 2013. You need to keep track of the current head of the list. I've named this global `doglist`. Then use a local variable `list` to move through the list. There is one tricky case - when you insert before the head of the list you need to make this the new head of the list.

```
struct dog
{
    char name[50];
    int genderValue;  
    char breed[50];
    int age;
    float weight;
    struct dog * next;
};

struct dog *doglist = NULL;

int dogadd(char* name, char* genderValueString, char* breed, int age, float weight)
{
    struct dog * list = doglist;    // save head of list
    int count = 0;
    int curGen = 1;

    struct dog *temp = (dog *)malloc(sizeof(struct dog));
    strcpy(temp->name, name);
    strcpy(temp->breed, breed);
    temp->age = age;
    temp->weight = weight;

    if (strcmpi(genderValueString, "male") == 0) {
        curGen = 0;
    }
    temp->genderValue = curGen;

    if (list == NULL) {
        temp->next = list;
        doglist = temp;
        return 1;
    }

    while (list != NULL) {
        if (strcmpi(list->name, name) == 0 && list->age == age) {
            return 0;
        }
        list = list->next;
    }

    list = doglist;             // restore the head of the list
    struct dog * prev = NULL;   // keep the previous list node so we can point it to the inserted entry
    while (list != NULL) {
        int nameCompare = strcmpi(list->name, name);
        if ( nameCompare > 0 || (nameCompare == 0 && list->age > age) ) {

            temp->next = list;
            if (prev != NULL)
                prev->next = temp;
            // if we are inserting before the current head of the list we need to make this the new head
            if (list == doglist)
                doglist = temp;
            list = temp;
            return 1;
        }
        if (list->next == NULL) {
            // Nothing greater than this, so add it to end
            list->next = temp;
            temp->next = NULL;
            return 1;
        }
        prev = list;
        list = list->next;
    }
    return 0;
}

void main()
{
    dogadd("Sybil", "female", "red heeler", 7, 40.1);
    dogadd("Pepi", "male", "chihuahua", 5, 3.3);
    dogadd("Goliath", "male", "bulldog", 9, 20.5);
    dogadd("Harry", "male", "golden retriever", 9, 35.6);
    dogadd("ZsaZsa", "female", "poodle", 3, 10.5);
    dogadd("Bruce", "male", "german shepherd", 9, 42.7);
    dogadd("Sybil", "female", "red heeler", 7, 40.1); // check it isn't added again
    struct dog * list = doglist;
    while (list != NULL) {
        printf("Dog name=%s sex=%d, breed=%s, age=%d, weight=%f\n", list->name, list->genderValue, list->breed, list->age, list->weight);
        list = list->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I'm still running into this problem where it will only let me add a few names to the list but then stops.

Comment: Whoops - forgot to point the previous list node to the newly inserted node. I didn't have a test case which inserted a new entry between 2 existing entries, which would have exposed this bug.

Comment: Thank you so much, this really helped me clarify how the linked lists function.

Comment: `(dog *)malloc...` --> `(struct dog *)malloc...` in C. Also such cast is not required in C.